Obtaining a simpler expression for the bound on Gisin's inequality: $S \leq \sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}(n-2 r)\binom{n}{r}$.
The Family of Bell Inequalities obtained in this link on elegant Bell Inequalities is well established.

I was recently trying to work on simplifying the general form of one such "elegant" inequality.
In this regard, I got stuck at the following stage where the following relation must hold:
$$
n\binom{n-1}{\left\lfloor\left(n - 1\right)/2\right\rfloor} =
\sum_{r = 0}
^{\left\lfloor\left(n - 1\right)/2\right\rfloor}
\left(n - 2r\right)\binom{n}{r}
$$
where, $\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor$ denotes the floor function and other symbols have their usual meanings.

I can see numerically that it holds good but can't seem to find an analytical way to show it.



Any help/hint/explicit proof of this is appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Hint:  consider the separate cases of $n$ being odd or even.
